# Return(self.write) object from handler tornado

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, tornado

How can I return a object from the tornado Handler function.

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        member = Member(name='ABCD',surname='XYZ').save()
        self.write(member)
```

I get this error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

I am using Tornado 3.1.1

Comment: I take it that `memeber` is a typo (please copy and paste your code)... What part of "is not JSON serializable" is confusing you... What do you expect it to return? What is `Member`? etc..

Comment: Member is the ORM Class of SQLAlchemy And I am creating the member and then I just want to return its object.

Comment: That's what I mean... what do you expect its "object" to be? Do you want to return JSON... if so, do you want just return its name and surname? If not - what else do you expect to happen here?

Comment: i just to return object.

Comment: What does that mean!!!? What parts of the object? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am talking about the object of the SQLAlchemy class.And I want to return the whole object with its attributes.Is it possible.I have written a very simple example above.

Answer (score 0):

the input of self.write should be json serializable, try this :

```
self.write(member.__dict__)
```

If your dictionary contain another object this will not work, You can always do something like :

```
class Member:
    def todict(self):
        memberdict = {}
        memberdict["name"] =  self.name
        memberdict["otherthing"] =  self.otherthing
        return memberdict
```

and :

```
self.write(member.todict())
```

Or maybe you can provide more details so I can propose a more suitable solution.